# how to work with Softkeyboard and hardkeyboard simultaneously in one application in android

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, barcode-scanner

I am working in an application where i need to connect with External barcode Scanner as hard keyboard and Some edit text boxes to input in the application. In earlier version like Kitkat all is working fine. Scanner is doing it's job as well as onclick of Edittext, softkeyboard is sucessfully opening but now i am testing this applicition in Lollipop and getting softkeyboard blocked. I am not able to input anything in Edittext. This is a blocker for my application. Is this a legacy bug for android?

If anyboady has a solution to make it working please let me know. Any help would be highly appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

In Marshmallow (and I assume it's the same for lollipop), click on any text input after you've paired your keyboard or scanner.

[image: Android's on-screen navigation buttons with the input options button showing]
*image via [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-switch-keyboards-android-lollipop)*

That should bring up the input options dialog with a toggle to display the soft keyboard when a hardware keyboard is attached.

[image: Input method dialog with option to show virtual input method when hardware input device is attached]

Comment: Yes, this is what is displaying but not so much user friendly from user's point of view.